# i can not understand Success Criterion 1.3.6: Identify Purpose

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, wcag

I see examples here
https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/identify-purpose.html
and first one of them is obvious: i should use ARIA landmarks, but the second example:
"The links in the navigation of a website are marked-up so that users can add their own icons" is not clear for me.
Can you provide some simple HTML example or explanation how i can allow users to add their own icons?

Comment: Duplicate: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/119225/wcag-2-1-1-3-6-identify-purpose-how-do-you-meet-the-icon-requirements-for-thi

Comment: indeed a duplicate.  see my answer in the linked question.